# Не срабатывает хендлер кнопки из-за состояния

Tags: python

Есть кнопка которая выдаёт сообщение с reply_markup и переводит юзера в State

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "but_1")  # Действие для нашедшего
async def form(message: types.Message):
message_obj = await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, text='1.Скажите, что вы нашли?\n(Просто '
                                                                        'название предмета. '
                                                                        'Например: телефон, кошелёк, карта)',
                                     reply_markup=markup.cancel_btn)
await bot.delete_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id, message_id=message_obj.message_id - 1)
await message.answer()
await u_info.thing.set()
```

Хендлер , который отвечает за обработку markup.cancel_btn не срабатывает из-за того, что пользователь находиться в состоянии u_info.thing

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(lambda c: c.data == "cancel_btn")  # Действие для возврата
async def cancel(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
await state.finish()
await message.answer()
await begin(message)
```

Состояние не сбрасывается state.finish()
Кнопка не работает. Подскажите, как решить проблему?
Не срабатывает хендлер обработки кнопки cancel_btn
Спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не срабатывает хендлер обработки кнопки "cancel_btn"

Comment: Укажите, какие библиотеки вы использовали и хотя бы расставьте отступы. Код должен быть читаем, чтобы с ним стали разбираться люди